# Access is denied while running a C output

Tags: c, installation, windows-installer

I am getting an error while running the output(a.exe) of a C program. Command prompt showing "Access is denied". I have reinstalled gcc but same problem is arriving. [Here is the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgT5W.png)

Comment: Well, what is your program trying to access?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not use images. Copy the text and format it as code. Also please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). No one knows what your program does. Maybe it tries to delete everything in `C:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That output is seen, when you try to run a x64 binary on a x86 system.
But there are numerous other possibilities.

Another likely possibility is your Antivirus realtime scanning.
Be sure it does not block access for you.

---

Provide more details and I'll update this accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, problems is solved. It was happening because of Antivirus real time scanning.

Comment: Then feel free to accept the answer. One of my best crystal ball answers :D